# Touch node selection doesn't work cocos2d objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i'm working on a node selection procedure.
i have an array of CCDrawNode objects and i need to do something with the selected node
I do something like this :

```
  CGPoint TOUCHLOC            = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
  for (int j=0; j<=[theArray count]-1; j++)
 {
       node              = [theArray objectAtIndex:j];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(node.boundingBox, TOUCHLOC))
   {
       return node;
   }
 }
```

Also tried  something like this:

```
 float left             = node.boundingBox.origin.x    - node.boundingBox.size.width;
float right             = node.boundingBox.origin.x    + node.boundingBox.size.width;
float top               = node.boundingBox.origin.y    + node.boundingBox.size.height;
float bottom            = node.boundingBox.origin.y    - node.boundingBox.size.height;
CGRect r              = CGRectMake(left, bottom, right - left, top - bottom);
   OR
CGRect r                = CGRectMake(left, bottom, top - bottom , right - left );

if (CGRectContainsPoint(r, TOUCHLOC))
{
    return node;
}
```

This procedure was working perfect, but i updated the framework and the method 
[touch locationInWorld]; is deprecated
Now is 
[touch locationInView: [touch view]];

This does't work correctly sometimes selects an incorrect node or none.
Does someone knows the correct way to select the node

Thanks in advance!